# I want to Enlarge my JButton Image when my mouse hovers over it

Tags: java, eclipse, image, button, jbutton

I can't figure this out for the life of me. What I want to happen is when my mouse hovers over the "Start" `JButton` in the menu to enlarge it by like 50-100px. What is a way to do that, that would work with my code here?
thanks in advance! "I'm using java eclipse btw" don't know if that helps or not

```
//START_Button
    JButton button = new JButton("Start");
    frame.pack();
    JTextPane TEXT = new JTextPane();
    BufferedImage buttonIcon;
    try {
        buttonIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\GOULDEN\\Desktop\\MENU_START.png"));
        button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon));
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(button);
        button.setBounds(500,250,300,75);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement  `MouseListener` and use the `mouseEntered()` and `mouseExited()` to make your button bigger.

Declare the variables that will be accessed in other methods as [instance variables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm)  to be able to access them.

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Demo extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    private JButton startButton;


    public Demo() {

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        this.setLayout(null);        

        startButton = new JButton("Start");                                   
        startButton= new JButton(new ImageIcon("path/to/image.jpg"));
        startButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        startButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        startButton.setBounds(1, 2, 100, 25);
        startButton.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        startButton.addMouseListener(this);

        this.add(startButton);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new Demo();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        startButton.setSize(400, 125);
        this.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        startButton.setSize(100, 25);
        this.repaint();
    }              
    }
```

btw,  there is really no need to use the `bufferedImage` if you aren't going to use your image properties, so just insert the image location directly into `ImageIcon` so you can remove the `try-catch` block

```
new JButton(new ImageIcon("path/to/image.jpg"));
```

Check out these links to read more about the topics used in your example.

1. [Variable Scopes](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)
2. [MouseListener implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)
3. [Working With Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html)

Comment: I added the MouseEntered and put the button.setSize(400,125); but it says button cannot be resolved, which I think is because it can't access the JButton "button" but I don't know how to let the Public void mouseEntered have access to it. sorry if it's a simple fix I'm pretty new to code